# (Negative) Gradient and Orientability of its flow.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, orientation, morse-theory, gradient-flows

Before asking my question, I put the necessary definitions and some context. If you are used with Morse Theory, you can skip the text within [[[...]]].

[[[Let me first define what I mean by gradient flow. Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on some orientable closed manifold $M$. For $\xi \in M$, let's consider the initial value problem for smooth curves $\eta:\mathbb{R}\to M$ given by

$$\eta'(t)=X(\eta(t)), \ \ \ \ \eta(0)=\xi.$$

Clearly, since $M$ is closed, the solution $\eta=\eta_\xi$ exists for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. My diff geo professor called it *the trajectory of flow line through $\xi$*. The *flow generated by* $X$ is defined as the smooth map $((\phi: \mathbb{R}\times M\to M):(t,\xi)\mapsto \eta_\xi(t))$. Thus, for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ this gives rise to a diffeomorphism $((\phi_t:M\to M):\xi \mapsto\phi_t(\xi))$, which my diff geo prof called *time-$t$ map*.

Let me, furthermore, put a bit more of context to my question (Morse Theory notation). Let Crit$_k(f)$ be the set of critical points of index $k$ of a Morse function $f$. Let then, $x\in$Crit$_{k+1}(f)$ and let $y\in$Crit$_k(f)$. Let

$$W^u(x):=\{a\in M | \lim_{t\to +\infty}\phi_t(a)=x\} \ \ \ and \ \ \ W^u(y):=\{b\in M | \lim_{t\to -\infty}\phi_t(b)=y\},$$

denote respectively the unstable manifold of $x$ and the stable manifold of $y$. Then, one might define the *connecting manifold from x to y* as

$$_xM_y:=W^u(x)\cap W^s(y).$$

If $\theta$ is a regular value of $f$ lying in $(f(x),f(b))$, we can construct the space of connecting orbits from $x$ to $y$ as

$$_x\tilde{M}_y=_x\tilde{M}_y|_\theta:=W^u(x)\cap W^s(y)\cap f^{-1}(\theta).$$

This set represents precisely the orbits of the negative gradient flow ($X=-\nabla f$) running from x to y, because every orbit intersects the level hypersurface exactly once. Note that for the critical points we choose, $\dim(_x\tilde{M}_y)=0$ so that $_x\tilde{M}_y$ corresponds to a set of points.]]]

Now, let $u\in \ _x\tilde{M}_y$. Let's identify $_x M_y^u$ with the **connected** of component of $_x M_y$ **containing** $u$. Note that $\dim(_x M_y^u)=1$.

**Finally, here's my question**. The author of the paper claims that there's is an orientation for $_x M_y^u$ provided by the flow -- i.e. there's something in the relation

$$\phi_t'(u)=-X(\phi_t(u)),$$

that provides a way to get an orientation on that space.

I just do not see why this is true. Is there some theorem on gradient inducing orientation on the corresponding flow I am missing? Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: I think I got it with a dimensionality argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make some choices. Let us choose orientations for each unstable manifold $W^u(x)$. This is possible, because the $W^u(x)$ are contractible (hence orientable). This choice of orientation of the unstable manifolds provides an *coorientation* of all the stable manifolds, i.e. provides an orientation of the normal bundle of the stable manifold.

Now ${}_xM_y:=W^u(x)\cap W^s(y)$ is a transverse intersection of an oriented and a co-oriented manifold, hence is oriented. It is a nice exercise to check that this is the case, and that the intersection of oriented submanifolds need not be oriented!

Now if the index of $x$ and $y$ differs by one, ${}_xM_y$ is a one dimensional oriented manifold. On this space there is a non-vanishing vector field: the gradient flow. A non-vanishing vector field on a one dimensional manifold also provides an orientation. Thus we can compare both orientations and get $+$ or $-$ signs.

Comment: That’s good and was pretty much the same argument I developed yesterday. I’m just not sure about the « a non vanishing vector field on 1 dim manifold also provides an orientation » part. Do you have any hints or links to the proof? Also, is a non vanishing vf on two dimensional manifold providing an orientation? Say that the index of x and y differs by 2 instead. I’m just curious! :-)

Comment: This might be because the space of one forms is isomorphic to the vector space of smooth vector fields on the same subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @HolomorphicGuy: What is your notion of orientation? Maybe a non-vanishing volume form? On a one-dimensional manifold a non-vanishing vector field give rise to such: Just take a form that maps the vector field to 1 pointwise. This will be a non-vanishing volume form